# Unicorn-UI: Buttons text moves (possibly overlapping styles?)

Tags: jquery, html, css

Attaching js fiddle link here first [js fiddle link here](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lb7gLyz/)

I'm having a little difficult time trying to create a button using [Unicorn UI Button library](http://unicorn-ui.com/buttons/) to open up modal window.

The problem I am encountering is the alignment of the text.
When my code is

```
<button class="button button-raised button-action button-circle button-extreme">Wireframe and Mockups</button>
```

The text is aligned properly as shown here
[image: Correctly Shown]
However, when I change the code by giving it a label so that I can have my modal window code working such as

```
<label for="window-1" button class="button button-raised button-action button-circle button-extreme">Wireframe and Mockups</button></label>
```

The text gets misaligned as shown.
[image: Incorrect]

I've tried changing the css styles in the buttons library as well as changing the css for the modal window, but I just cannot get the text alignment to stay the same when I apply the `"label for = "windows 1"` . Please help me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add `my-label` class at the end of your css styles and add it to your label element classes like this:

```
.my-label{
   display:table-cell;
   vertical-align:middle;
}

<label for="window-1" button class="... my-label">Wireframe and Mockups</label>
```

if you don't like to add a new class you also can add those css rules to `.button-raised.button-action` css selector like this:

```
.button-raised.button-action {
    ...
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
}
```

**I Also updated your [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6Lb7gLyz/3/)**

Comment: Thank you, could you please tell me what it did when the .my-label has been added?

Comment: @axchink, `display: table-cell` forces label tag to behavior like a td tag it also forces label to has the same height as the container. and `vertical-align: middle;` aligns it to the center of container, hope that helps